# How do I get the arrows on jQuery jScrollpane to show? (& mousewheel behaviors)?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jscrollpane, mousewheel, trackpad

I am using jScrollpane to allow the overflow on divs.

The scrollbars are showing up and working correctly, (they move and allow content to scroll) but the arrows are not showing up.

Also, the mouse wheel / trackpad scroll is not working (on laptops) but is working on iPad 2. So (on laptops) you can click and drag the scrollbar to see the content, but cannot swipe the trackpad / mouse wheel whereas on iPad it is the opposite, you can swipe (track) over the text and the scroll works, but cannot drag the scrollbar.

**1 - How do I get the arrows to show?

2 - How do I get the scroll to work with mousewheel / trackpad?**

- I am less concerned with the iPad, it is functioning: I thought it was worth mentioning, to help diagnose the trackpad issue.

http://thepicturelab.tv/creatives/norman-bonney

PS. The site is developed in wordpress in the sandbox theme.

Answer (score 0):

To get the arrows, don't forget to add `{showArrows: true}`

example:

```
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows: true});
```

to use the scroll wheel, add the jQuery MouseWheel plugin: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/script/jquery.mousewheel.js

Study the examples at the jScrollpane site: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Comment: OK, i see what i did: i had called the {showArrows: true} in a different class. thanks for noticing that.  as for the other part, i do have the (jquery.mousewheel.js) attached but do not see why it is behaving like that? or not behaving?

Comment: @Adam it is there indeed, but I noticed your version is smaller than the one provided in the link I gave you. Also, try the un-minified version and see if it works?